# Difference between HTML5 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, terminology

Is there a difference between HTML5 and jQuery, or is jQuery an instrument I can use in the HTML5 logic ?

I am a little confused by the terminology I guess and I hope someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) is a [markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language). [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) is a Javascript library. They're not the same thing.

They are related however: Javascript code embedded in (or referenced from) HTML5 documents can use the objects and methods provided by jQuery to perform its tasks.

Answer (score 7):

jQuery is Javascript

HTML5 is HTML

Comment: +1 why the down vote? its simple enough for OP to understand ( based on the question standard.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a javascript library. In the other hand HTML5 is the latest version of HTML. One is programming language, javascript, the other is markup language.

HTML is used for the structure of a web document, but javascript is used to control user's interaction with the HTML document, for example a click on HTML element.

---

Read more for HTML5: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5

Read more for Javascript: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript

Read more for jQuery: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com) is a JavaScript framework, [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) is a language for HTML structure/presentation.